# Label for Select Form Helper

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I"m having trouble with CakePHP3's Form Helper class.

When I create a text input field like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('fieldname');
```

When the input field is "required", a label appears in bold. This is fine.

However, when I create a **select** field like this:

```
echo $this->Form->select('fieldname', [1,2,3,4,5]);
```

The select field is created however there is no label at all. I can add it manually using:

```
echo $this->Form->label('fieldname');
```

However in cases where the select is a required field, the font is not correct (required labels show up **bold** with a red * following them). I've narrowed this down to the CSS only applying to nested label tags (so when I create a label tag, it's not inside a div tag like the labels for the text inputs are).

I'd like to avoid manually inserting HTML code to achieve my desired result, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: why can't you use `Form->input` instead of `Form->select`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?= $this->Form->input('fieldName', ['type' => 'select', 'options' => ['0' => 'Option1' , '1' => 'Option2'], 'empty' => __('(choose one)'), 'label' => __('LabelName')]);?>
```

or

```
$sizes = ['s' => 'Small', 'm' => 'Medium', 'l' => 'Large'];

<?= $this->Form->input('fieldName', ['type' => 'select', 'options' => $sizes, 'default' => 'm', 'label' => __('LabelName')]);?>
```