# Cakephp 2.3: Html Form Select default value beeing ignored

Tags: html, forms, cakephp

I have a piece of code what returns me the value I would like to set as default value within a form-input select element.

```
echo $this->Form->input('city', array(
    'label' => __('Ort'), 
    'empty' => __('Bitte wählen'), 
    'options' => $getCities, 
    'id' => 'city', 
    'class' => 'styled-select', 
    'default' => $showSelectedCityName
));
```

`$getCities` is filled, as I can see all my city names

`$showSelectedCityName` is not empty at any time I can see that when I have a `debug($showSelectedCityName)` running, see on screenshot debug message line 122

please see this screenshot:

[image]

So why cake ignores this default value?

Anyone any idea on that?

Comment: works in cakephp 2.7, don't have a running 2.3 enviroment to test. Are you sure the two strings are exactly the same? Maybe the hyphens are not the same unicode char

Comment: also: the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#common-options) says: _The value is used if the data passed to the form does not contain a value for the field (or if *no data is passed at all*)._

Comment: what value has `$showSelectedCityName` ? this shoud have index element of `$getCities` e.g.: '000-4'

Comment: @JacekBBudzyñski the OP painted a big red arrow showing that the debug of `$showSelectedCityName` gives `000-4`

Comment: @arilia the big red arrow is showing `$getCities` results, check my answer in this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674682/label-for-select-form-helper/)

Comment: there are two big arrows in the picture. The smaller one points to the result of `debug($showSelectedCityName)` at line 122 as stated in the question